Lower bound on the singular values of a matrix with uniformly distributed random numbers
Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ whose entries are randomly generated and uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, is there a formula for a lower bound on the singular values of $A$? (Of course NOT $\sigma(A)_{i}>0$) If so, could you provide a reference (book, article) where this result can be found?
